# Access to Windows computer to use py2exe

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, py2exe

For many years, I have been distributing my Python application using py2exe and py2app.  I no longer have access to a windows computer, and I am now looking for network access to a windows computer solely to use py2exe to build my app.

Could I use an Amazon EC2 instance to do this?  Or is there another, better solution out there?  I am willing to pay but want to keep it cheap.

Comment: You can look into getting a Windows VPS. The best solution would really be to buy an old Windows machine off someone for a little money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are under Linux, you can try Wine:

- http://www.winehq.org/

Comment: I'd prefer to get remote access to a windows machine since I will have high confidence that it will work.  I'd rather not put a lot of effort into trying wine and then find out it doesn't work...

Comment: OK, but I don't think it's a lot of effort - on most of the Linux distributions you can have Wine installed in a few minutes.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself yet, but I've heard from other py2exe users that py2exe works under Wine so this is the best solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

Run windows within a Virtual Machine of some kind.

### OR

Alternatively test [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) it claims to do this (not tested myself).

Comment: Wouldn't I have to pay several hundred dollars to get a windows license?

Comment: Yes you would need to acquire license, however Windows 7 trial can be extended to 120 days... perhaps until you find another solution. Or at least you previously could.

Comment: Added further PyInstaller alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I have a MacBook. I run Microsoft's Remote Desktop Connection for Mac and log into my employer's Windows machine. Maybe the local library would let you do something like that.

Alternatively, there are vendors offering [free shell accounts](http://shells.red-pill.eu/) but these to be Linux or Unix only. Who knows, you might find someone willing to risk their Windows box in the same way.